# change error message under shipping method

Tags: shipping-methods

under shipping method we are getiing error message

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

we have to chnage this error message.

please help me where we can edit this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change this error message to something else then would ask you to override the template file.

This `theme/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` file is responsible for that error.

**To override this template**

Create a file `theme/layout/local.xml` and have this code:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
  <reference name="available">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available_new.phtml</template>
      </action>
  </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>

<checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available_new.phtml"/>
</checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
```

Now copy all content from `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` and paste in `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available_new.phtml` then edit the message as you require.

You will be editing this line:

```
<p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy your theme folder then edit

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method
```

Here you change your error message

```
<p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
```